# How to create variation to get date value in Odoo

Tags: odoo

this code I have date.tm_year to collect year value and I have date.tm_month to collect month value now I want to create sum_date to coolect date and month for make condition if sum_date &gt 04/01/2023
I just try to   and
 syntax error T^T

I just try to make condition year > 2022 and month > 4 but it not working when date in 1/1/2024 and I just try to make variable to collect date  but it syntax error

Comment: <t t-set="sum_date" t-value="%date.tm_year/%date.tm_mon/%(date.strftime('%d'))"/> it syntax error

Comment: and I try <t t-set="sum_date" t-value="%date.tm_year/%date.tm_mon/%1"/>  but still error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have a date object in "date" variable, why not just checking if the string representation of this date is > 2023-01-04 ? (I expect your date 04/01/2023 to be Day/Month/Year. If it's Month/Day/Year change the date with 2023-04-01)

So it would be:

```
<t t-if="date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') > '2023-01-04'"></t>
```

If you really need to use the date.tm_year and date.tm_month, e.g. if date isn't a Date or Datetime object, you can recreate the datetime object by using :

```
<t t-set="dt_date" t-value="datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date.tm_year) + '-' + str(date.tm_month) + '-01', '%Y-%m-%d')"/>
```

Then the code before this one will work :)

But that's redundant, you can simple compose the string and compare both strings:

```
<t t-if="(str(date.mt_year) + '-' + str(date.my_month) + '-01') > '2023-04-01'"> ... </t>
```

Anyway, when comparing dates in python, try to compare OR datetime objects, OR string in the format '%Y-%m-%d'.

If you need help don't hesitate commenting here :)